# Calculate length of an array without blowing up the stack

Tags: f#

How do I calculate length of an array without blowing up the stack? My two attempts do not look good to me

```
let rec slowComputeLength xs = match xs with
                               | x::xss -> 1 + slowComputeLength xss
                               | _ -> 0

let computeLength xs = List.fold (fun acc _ -> acc + 1) 0 xs
```

I can think of passing an accumulator in the first version of pattern match but that makes the API ugly

```
let rec slowComputeLength xs acc = match xs with
                                   | x::xss -> slowComputeLength xss acc+1
                                   | _ -> 0
```

Is List.fold the right way or is it creating something like below which i believe is hitting stack too?

```
(1 + (1 + (1 + (...))))?
```

PS - I am doing this as an exercise, ideally we should use Array.Length.

Comment: ah yes it was an exercise. Let me add that to the question. :)

Comment: Wow, the expression `slowComputeLength xss acc+1` is *evil*. Together with `_ -> 0`, it actually leads to the correct result, but doesn't at all do what it looks like it's supposed to do. It's not tail recursive: note that function application has higher precedence than the `+` operator!

Comment: `List.fold` loops, perhaps via tail recursion as in the posted answer, so it will not blow the stack.

Comment: Surely you mean List not Array.

Comment: Yes I meant List not Array :), my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual trick is to define a nested recursive function that keeps the accumulator:

```
let computeLength xs = 
  let rec loop acc xs = 
    match xs with
    | _::xs -> loop (acc+1) xs
    | _ -> acc
  loop 0 xs
```

Here, the `loop` function has the additional accumulator parameter, but it does not make the API of the outer `computeLength` function ugly, because the `loop` function is nested and never called directly by the user.

Comment: Did you think of the answer and it appeared?  That was less than one minute.

Comment: I was just browsing SO randomly and the question appeared :). To be fair, I did not test the code...

Comment: Thanks, also is my assumption correct that List.Fold would create stack frames as it iterates? Is the List folded (sorry if that is not the right term) at the very end of iteration, or does it accumulate as it goes along?

Comment: Should it not be `| _ -> acc`

Comment: @RohitSharma no, List.fold does not create stack frames.  It can be easily implemented with a nested recursive function as in this answer.  In fact, it seems to have been implemented that way; see https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L237.